# How is Spring Boot configuring my Jackson ObjectMapper here?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, dependency-injection

I'm trying to understand how Spring/Spring Boot is managing DI for an app that I've been put in charge of maintaining. Inside that app I see a `MyAppInjector` Groovy file that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
class MyAppInjector {
    @Autowired
    void configureJackson(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        SimpleModule jacksonModule = new SimpleModule()
                .addDeserializer(AccountDeserializer, new AccountDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(PhoneNumberDeserializer, new PhoneNumberDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(AddressDeserializer, new AddressDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(ContactDeserializer, new ContactDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(CustomerDeserializer, new CustomerDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(DeploymentInfoDeserializer, new DeploymentInfoDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(ServiceAgreementDeserializer, new ServiceAgreementDeserializer())

        objectMapper.registerModule(jacksonModule)
    }
}
```

However I don't see `configureJackson(...)` invoked from anywhere inside my app source code. I *assume* that this method is configuring the Jackson `ObjectMapper`, used by Spring to serialize JSON into POJOs.

**However**, how does Spring know to configure the `ObjectMapper` here? Does it look for anything annotated with `@Configuration` and then see it has a Jackson `ObjectMapper` registered somewhere, and pass it into this `configureJackson(...)` method? Looks like magic to me...

And is this true of *any* method in a class annotated with `@Configuration`? Meaning can I create a method like:

```
@Configuration
class MyAppInjector {
    @Autowired
    Fizz fizz(Buzz buzz) {
      new Fizz(buzz)
    }

    @Autowired
    void configureJackson(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        SimpleModule jacksonModule = new SimpleModule()
                .addDeserializer(AccountDeserializer, new AccountDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(PhoneNumberDeserializer, new PhoneNumberDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(AddressDeserializer, new AddressDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(ContactDeserializer, new ContactDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(CustomerDeserializer, new CustomerDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(DeploymentInfoDeserializer, new DeploymentInfoDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(ServiceAgreementDeserializer, new ServiceAgreementDeserializer())

        objectMapper.registerModule(jacksonModule)
    }
}
```

...and expect Spring to intelligently look for a `Buzz` instance to pass into the `Fizz` at construction-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringBoot instantiates ObjectMapper on its own, as it is used by Spring in convert Java object to JSON and vice versa. So if it finds Spring boot in the classpath it will load the objectMapper. Now in your configureJackson method, you have reference of ObjectMapper and @Autowired annotation so Spring will provide the instance of ObjectMapper to this method.

The `@Autowired` annotation is doing the magic which you are referring to. `@Autowired`

```
Fizz fizz(Buzz buzz) {
  new Fizz(buzz)
}
```

In this example Apring will inject the Buzz instance in fizz method.